# Change img src with onclick method

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I would like to change my img source when I click on the img.
(When I click on img1 I want to see img2. When I click on img2 I want to see img3. Etc.)

I've checked many post before posting myself. Many of them offer the same answer. This is my code :

```
<article id="article"><h1 class="titre">ROADTRIP</h1>    

<img id="roadtrip" src="img/roadtrip.jpg" alt="" onclick="clickimg()" />

    <script>
    function clickimg() {
        if (document.getElementById("roadtrip").getAttribute('src')=='img/roadtrip.jpg')
        {
            document.getElementById("roadtrip").setAttribute('src') = 'img/roadtrip2.png';
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("roadtrip").getAttribute('src') == 'img/roadtrip2.png')
        {
            document.getElementById("roadtrip").src = 'img/roadtrip.jpg';
        }
    }
    </script>
</article>
```

My image appear but when I click on it, nothing happen

Comment: You should be getting an error in the console. Take a look at [the documentation for `setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Comment: Also you should not store your data in the DOM. Store the image source addresses into a JS array, and keep book of the index for showing images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code, use `.src` not `.setAttribute`.

```html
<article id="article"><h1 class="titre">ROADTRIP</h1>    

<img id="roadtrip" src="https://spaceholder.cc/700x500" alt="" onclick="clickimg()" />

    <script>
    function clickimg() {
        if (document.getElementById("roadtrip").getAttribute('src')=='https://spaceholder.cc/700x500')
        {
            document.getElementById("roadtrip").src = 'http://www.placebear.com/700/500';
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("roadtrip").getAttribute('src') == 'http://www.placebear.com/700/500')
        {
            document.getElementById("roadtrip").src = 'https://spaceholder.cc/700x500';
        }
    }
    </script>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks, the two methods are working. I had the solution but didn't see the mistake I did.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("roadtrip").setAttribute('src', 'img/roadtrip2.png');
```

Related [setAttribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Comment: Or, alternatively, just use `.src = ` as the OP does in the latter half of the code.

Comment: Thanks, the two methods are working. I had the solution but didn't see the mistake I did.

Comment: `getAttribute` just return value, not point to src, it gets a clone of src.
If you change the clone, the original is  not changed.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, you should not store your data in the DOM. Doing so is overly complex, a nightmare to maintain and dead slow to execute. Instead, store the image addresses into a JS array, and keep book of the index for showing images, something like this:

In the HTML, pass the event object: `onclick="clickimg(event)"`, or rather add the event listener in the script:

```
const imgs = [
    'img/image1.jpg',
    'img/image2.jpg',
    'img/image3.jpg'
];
let index = 0;
document.getElementById('roadtrip').addEventListener(
    'click', clickimg // If you'll do this, remove the onclick attribute from the img tag
);
function clickimg (e) {
    e.target.src = imgs[index]; // Change the src of the clicked image
    index = ++index % imgs.length; // Increase index, shows the first image when the length of the array is reached
}
```

This way the image addresses are easy to maintain, if you need more images, just add an address to `imgs` array. Or you can change or remove some of the images just by manipulating the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
document.getElementById("roadtrip").setAttribute('src', SRC_Value);
```

or:

```
document.getElementById("roadtrip").src =  SRC_Value;
```

See the snippet below!

```js
var src1 = "https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/extension/isAllowedAccess/sample-128.png"
var src2 = "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/0ca0ca_b9a2fe29d4be46179bea5a20ae7afd12~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_672,h_316,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/png-sample-1.webp"

function clickimg() {
        if (document.getElementById("roadtrip").getAttribute('src')=== src1)
        {
            document.getElementById("roadtrip").setAttribute('src', src2);
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("roadtrip").getAttribute('src') === src2)
        {
            document.getElementById("roadtrip").src = src1;
        }
}
```

```html
<article id="article"><h1 class="titre">ROADTRIP</h1>    
    <img id="roadtrip" src="https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/extension/isAllowedAccess/sample-128.png" alt="" onclick="clickimg()" />
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others specified, you have to give the RHS of the expression as the second argument in setAttribute. Also, did you check if it is even going into the if condition block to set the attribute value?
It could be the case that none of your condition returns true and you might have to use indexOf or the relative image path instead for an exact match.