# change image and make button visible with a click

Tags: javascript

my apologies if this is not the correct place to ask this, but i am very new to using javascript and am wondering if its possible to change an image's source and make a button visible on the same click? to show what i mean better i have created a simple gif for more clarity :-)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvol6.gif)

explanations as to why things do as they do would also be a huge help. i think i know how to make an image change upon click, but with the added button appearing i'm not sure how to go about it at all. will remove this post if need be, thanks!

Comment: You can use [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#examples) event on `<img />` and change it's [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#example)'s `src` value and handle show `<button />` in the same function.

Comment: Refer for `<img />` src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484120/change-img-src-with-onclick-method

Comment: Refer for `<button />`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081656/how-can-i-show-and-hide-a-button-after-click